# Rails carrierwave manual file "upload" wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

Schema:

```
  create_table "playlists", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name",                                 null: false
    t.text     "description",             default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                           null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                           null: false
    t.string   "file",        limit: 256, default: "", null: false
  end

  create_table "devices", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "login"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.integer  "playlist_id"
    t.string   "serial_number", default: "", null: false
  end
```

Model:

```
class Playlist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :media_deployments 
  has_many :media_items, :through => :media_deployments
  has_many :devices

  after_save :playlist_updated
  before_save :create_playlist_file

  mount_uploader :file, PlaylistFileUploader

  private
    def create_playlist_file
      if !media_items.empty?
        tempfile = Tempfile.new(['playlist', '.m3u'])
        self.media_deployments.order(:playlist_position).each do |deployment|
          tempfile.puts deployment.media_item.file_identifier
        end
        tempfile.close
        self.file = tempfile
        tempfile.unlink
      end
    end

    def playlist_updated
      self.devices.each do |d|
    puts "******************\n\n"
    puts "playlist by device: " + d.playlist.inspect + " url " + d.playlist.file_url + " new_record?" + d.playlist.new_record?.to_s
    pp = Playlist.where("device_id" == d.id).first
    puts "playlist found: " + pp.inspect + " url " + pp.file_url + " new_record?" + pp.new_record?.to_s
    puts "******************\n\n"
      end
   end
end
```

Uploader:

```
class PlaylistFileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
  process :set_content_type
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
  def extension_white_list
    %w(m3u)
  end
  def filename
    "playlist.m3u" if original_filename
  end
end
```

So, whenever a playlist object updated m3u file gets created and attached to it.
The problem is here:

```
******************
playlist by device: #<Playlist id: 15, name: "test1", description: "", created_at: "2014-10-21 04:12:20", updated_at: "2014-11-14 04:55:16", file: "playlist.m3u"> url /uploads/tmp/1415940916-15072-1149/playlist20141114-15072-1066hu7.m3u new_record?false
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "playlists".* FROM "playlists"  ORDER BY "playlists"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
playlist found: #<Playlist id: 15, name: "test1", description: "", created_at: "2014-10-21 04:12:20", updated_at: "2014-11-14 04:55:16", file: "playlist.m3u"> url /uploads/playlist/file/15/playlist.m3u new_record?false
******************
```

When I loop through devices I get the playlist with wrong file url. When I select the playlist manually it returns the same exact playlist object but with correct file url.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @jasa No, I had to do workaround: find the object with `find` (not through association) and get `file_url` from it. In that case it works for me